# Which data structure to use for storing big amount of strings

Tags: java, data-structures

Well, to explain the problem-question...

I have:
One Big DB table filled with millions of entries (each entry may have an "n" amount of columns).

The concept:

I want to show to a web interface two lists (ex. "Available" and "Selected").
When a user moves an entry from one list to the other I need to store temporary the unique-id (type of string) of the entry to an "Unknown data structure" named "selected" in my server and when the user finally clicks submit I will pass this list further to an other application.

Sorting and filtering are done into the DB and then the full amount of data (in chunks) is loaded back to java, then every entry will be checked if it is selected and will be added to the list that is going to be displayed in the web interface.

```
for each entry{
  if(selected.contains(currentEntry.ID)){
    selectedList.add(currentEntry)
  }else{
    availableList.add(currentEntry)
  }
}
```

The lists selectedList and availableList will only hold few hundreds of entries (those that are displayed to the user, approximately a page with max 100-200 entries) so a list of type "entry" is good enough and holds my sorting.

The problem:
The structure "selected" must hold many thousands of ids (some times it may reaches million(s)).

The need:
I need fast access to find if the id exists (structure.contains(id)) so for sure I will use a hash structure.
I need the structure that will use the minimum Memory resources.

The non-need:
Good performance on deletion is not needed. Sorting is not needed.

Comment: Set will be best I think.

Comment: If it has to hold so many entries, you should probably dump it in a database table, with an extra id (e.g. a session-id of some type)

Comment: After a lot of testing I realized that all the Hash structures (HashSet, LinkedHashMap etc) perform approximately the same. The TreeSet was the worse-performance structure I tested, needing the most time to find and element.

I started facing problems of overflows to my Testsystems when i went over 200.000 elements (of course that has to do with the Hardware etc).

I will possibly go to the solution of using a DB table to hold the selected ids and fetch data direct from the DB using joins (either ways i would have used the db for sorting and filtering)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing I realized that all the Hash structures (HashSet, LinkedHashMap etc) perform approximately the same.

I started facing problems of overflows to my Testsystems when i went over 200.000 elements (of course that has to do with the Hardware etc).

I will possibly go to the solution of using a DB table to hold the selected ids and fetch data direct from the DB using joins (either ways i would have used the db for sorting and filtering)

Thanks to @DariusX. for the "winning" suggestion and everyone else for their help.

Answer (score 1):

mybe something where you have fast access like HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TreeSet`, javadoc says it *"provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)"*  and if you need to link something to your id, use a `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

1.Since you need to hold thousands of ids, well `HashMap` is one ans. It has very fast access if key known and fast insertion.

2.Generally, both `treemap` & `hashmap` are not synchronized, but `hashtable` is synchronized. Meanwhile, `hashtable` does not allow null keys or values. One the other hand `hashMap` allows one null key.

3.You can also go for `TreeMap` as `TreeMap` allows us to retrieve the elements in some sorted order defined by the user. Well, i think that  `TreeMap` is slower than `HashMap`

**Edit:**
Well after reading few articles i came across this one as well..

> Seriously though, you're better off staying away from Hashtable
>   altogether. For single-threaded apps, you don't need the extra
>   overhead of syncrhonisation. For highly concurrent apps, the paranoid
>   synchronisation might lead to starvation, deadlocks, or unnecessary
>   garbage collection pauses. Like Tim Howland pointed out, you might use
>   ConcurrentHashMap instead

So, i would go with `ConcurrentHashMap`

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` should provide the fast access and in most probability would be constant-time access, though I think if feasible you can run sample test to check if there are too high collision due to millions of entry and nature of your dataset.

This would certainly won't address your optimal memory requirement, what is the size you are expecting on holding millions of entries into a Java memory? If its very large footprint (say 1000's of MB), you might need to consider distributed caches or even consider indexing approaches.